# Is there a way to shorten the check name in GitHub PR?

Tags: github, github-actions

This is the check name in Github using Github Actions.

It contains the `workflow name` + `job id` + `step name` + `on condition`.

[image]

Is it possible to make it shorter, as we have with apps? SonarCloud, for example, only has a single name.

[image]

Removing the `name` parameter only makes it worse since github will use the full filename (plus path) instead of a single friendly name.

Comment: Isn't the SonarCloud check from an app integration, rather than a workflow?

Comment: Yes. That's the main difference. I couldn't find a way to have this name similar to what we have with app integration

Answer (score 4):

You can customise that by defining `run-name` on top level of your workflow.

`run-name: "SonarCloud Code Analysis"`

You can read about it in docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#run-name)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. `run-name` is only for the `Actions` tab. Inside the `Checks` inside the PR itself, it has no influence :(